# Using OrientDB in an OSGi environment

Tags: osgi, orientdb

I'm trying to build an application that uses an embedded OrientDB (currently "memory:") graph database.
I'm using OrientDB 2.2

I am using Eclipse bndtools for my development environment.

I have added orientdb-core and orientdb-graphdb osgi bundles as build dependencies to my bundle, but on its own that isn't enough, I need access to the tinkerpop blueprint classes as well. There doesn't seem to be a tinkerpop blueprints osgi bundle that I can see.

I can include the blueprints-core jar as a build dependency, and that gets rid of the compile errors, but I then get into all sorts of issues trying to resolve the bundles so I can run something. (the primary error there that I don't seem to be able to get rid of is a complain about not being able to resolve "com.carrotsearch.hppc" -- I include that in my bundle, and export it, but still no joy there)

Shouldn't orientdb-graphdb either depend on a suitable bundle, or include and export the classes?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running into the classic problem of wrapping a third-party, non-OSGi library as an OSGi bundle.

The best tutorial for this is on the [EnRoute site](http://enroute.osgi.org/tutorial_wrap/050-start.html). Note that you don't need to be using EnRoute for this tutorial to be relevant.